# How we can get email key that does not change after we move email from inbox folder to sent using Imap() php?

Tags: imap

Is there any unique key associated with email that does not change after we move email from one folder to another on email server using Imap() php

Answer (score 0):

In the web mail i created, i used both data (message number and folder) for reading and deleting etc and i works well.

If you want to get a unique id for each mail use this function imap_uid. It return the unique id from the mailbox folder and the message number.